# Bootstrap navbar misaligned dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with a couple of dropdowns. They have been modified to use a container to display 4 columns of dropdown content

[image]
[image]

Notice that for each dropdown on the navbar, the dropdown menu is not alligned with the container (gray area). I would like to have all dropdowns aligned with the container.

I tried absolute positioning this but it didn't work very well, and I'm wondering if there's a better bootstrap way of doing it?

code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#"
            class="dropdown-toggle"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false">
             Dropdown 1 <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#"
            class="dropdown-toggle"
            data-toggle="dropdown"
            role="button"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false">
             Dropdown 1 <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider" role="separator"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: We will need the CSS too...

Comment: make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: What `css` are you using for the drop-down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each your `dropdown-menu` contains `<div class="container">` which has fixed `width` corresponding to screen size.

You should manually set container width: `<div class="container" style="width:...">`

Or create css class for each screen size `<div class="container custom-width">`:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .custom-width {
    width: ... !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .custom-width {
    width: ...  !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .custom-width {
    width: ...  !important;
  }
}
```